# Speeding up Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer

I have read about how to speed up Internet Explorer from [here](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/43230-internet-explorer-download-connections-per-server-change.html)

I just want to know what is the maximum value we can set in Maximum Connections per Server for speeding up Internet Explorer.Whether setting up a value like 100 would help a lot for Automation? (Not for normal browsing though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you could [set it to any value you desire between 2 and 128](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330731(v=vs.85).aspx#http11_max_con) but if it is for automation, you should consider more suitable tools.

And setting it to **high value** could get your **connection refused by the server** depending on its configuration and make the testing experience very different from a normal user.

Comment: A thats right but Automation is all about testing out the functionalities right?

Comment: it is about testing the functionality in the **same conditions as the end user**, opening multiple connection to the server could adversely affect the browsing experience.